# How to fork ethereum and change native currency name

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc, hardforks

I am trying to fork Ethereum ( https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum ) but don't know:

1. How can I create a custom native currency(replacing ETH with custom name like PQR).
2. How will my native currency gets value on DEX?

PS: BSC is a fork of Geth-Ethereum, how did they changed the native currency ETH to BNB in the GETH code?

Comment: Voting to close this question, as the scope of the question is far too wide to be discussed here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I got the answer of first questio, i.e. the native currency symbol is defined on that wallet.

Comment: I dont know how my native token gets valuable? @Mikko